# Error 'Invalid object name INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, collation, case-sensitive

I'm getting an error when running the following code thru an `ASP/ C# .NET` page:

```
 SELECT 1 FROM [database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME='example_table'
```

The code runs perfectly when I run it in the `sql management studio query` window.
It's also only broken for 1 specific `server` - when I run on a different `server` with a different `connection string`, it works fine.

I've scoured the internet, and all I can seem to find as an answer is that there are issues with case sensitivity, but I'm using all uppercase, and the table in question is using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation` anyway.

Based on all this, I'm pretty sure it's some kind of permissions issue, but I'm not really sure where to look.

The error I'm getting:

> Invalid object name 'database.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'.

The connection string:

```
<add name="connectionName" connectionString="Data Source=servername; Initial Catalog=master; User ID=user; Password=pw" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

UPDATE:

Some more information:  I had adapted this code from some older VB stuff that basically does the same thing.  The VB code runs the same exact query on the same servers and databases, but it works.

The VB code:

```
Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionName").ConnectionString
Dim objConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM [database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME='example_table'", objConnection)
objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

objConnection.Open()
```

The C# and VB code both use the exact same connection string from web.config, so I suppose that leads me to doubt that it would be a permissions issue.  Still no clue what the problem is though.

Comment: The error you are getting would be useful, connection string that sort of thing

Comment: my apologies for not being clear, the error was the title: Invalid object name 'database.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'.  connection strings are fairly standard I suppose, <add name="connectionName" connectionString="Data Source=servername; Initial Catalog=master; User ID=user; Password=pw" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: doesnt work for me but I haven't got a database called database...

Comment: lol yes, you'd probably have to change the names, as I have

Comment: I get Invalid object name 'database.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' which suggests to me waht you are typing in sql server manager and waht your code is doing aren't exactly the same.

Comment: The web code is run using SqlDataAdapter.fill().  I can assure you that the sql being passed to that function via an SqlCommand object is identical to the sql I tried in my server manager, and the only difference between the sql posted here is the changed database and table names.

Comment: What database are you connected to when it runs and are you using the same user in sqlserver manager and the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch more debugging, I was able to determine that the code was actually running on the wrong server.  So, not really any way to find the bug based on what I'd posted, but I think Tony was on the right track based on the back-and-forth.

Answer (score 0):

It's a copy paste issue in your case I hope, change the [database] with your DB name.